# Vuejs2 firebase with electron error

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, electron

I have configured electron with vuejs and i would like to add firebae to my project so i have

In my main.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
let firebasconfig = {
  //config from firebase project 
};
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebasconfig);
```

But now am getting an error

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed 
for the current system
Expected directory: electron-v1.8-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v59-linux-x64-glibc]

   This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
   Original error: Cannot find module
```

I have tried running rebuild but still fails

What elese do i need to do for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I encouter the same issue with

- vue-electron 1.0.6
- firebase 5.4.2
- vuefire 1.4.5
- node 6.10.3

The following manipulation has worked for me. I have downgraded :

- firebase to 4.6.0
- vuefire to 1.4.4

Then ran `npm rebuild` and `yarn` and now it works.

I'm not sure all the things I have done are necessary. But for sure it looks like a problem with firebase.

Comment: please [edit] your post to make it look like an _answer_. Not a question, then an answer